# How to Wait for Completion of ANY Worker Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want a dispatcher thread that executes and retrieves results from a pool of worker threads.  The dispatcher needs to continuously feed work to the worker threads.  When ANY of the worker thread completes, the dispatcher needs to gather its results and re-dispatch (or create a new) worker thread.  It seems to me like this should be obvious but I have been unable to find an example of a suitable pattern.  A `Thread.join()` loop would be inadequate because that is really "AND" logic and I am looking for "OR" logic.

The best I could come up with is to have the dispatcher thread `wait()` and have the worker threads `notify()` when they are done. Though seems like I would have to guard against two worker threads that end at the same time causing the dispatcher thread to miss a `notify()`.  Plus, this seems a little bit inelegant to me.

Even less elegant is the idea of the dispatcher thread periodically waking up and polling the worker thread pool and checking each thread to see if it has completed via `isAlive()`.

I took a look at `java.util.concurrent` and didn't see anything that looked like it fit this pattern.

I feel that to implement what I mention above would involve a lot of defensive programming and reinventing the wheel. There's got to be something that I am missing.  What can I leverage to implement this pattern?

This is the single-threaded version.  `putMissingToS3()` would become the dispatcher thread and the capability represented in the `uploadFileToBucket()` would become the worker thread.

```
private void putMissingToS3()
{
    int reqFilesToUpload = 0;
    long reqSizeToUpload = 0L;

    int totFilesUploaded = 0;
    long totSizeUploaded = 0L;
    int totFilesSkipped = 0;
    long totSizeSkipped = 0L;

    int rptLastFilesUploaded = 0;
    long rptSizeInterval = 1000000000L;
    long rptLastSize = 0L;
    StopWatch rptTimer = new StopWatch();
    long rptLastMs = 0L;


    StopWatch globalTimer = new StopWatch();
    StopWatch indvTimer = new StopWatch();

    for (FileSystemRecord fsRec : fileSystemState.toList())
    {
        String reqKey = PathConverter.pathToKey(PathConverter.makeRelativePath(fileSystemState.getRootPath(), fsRec.getFullpath()));

        LocalS3MetadataRecord s3Rec = s3Metadata.getRecord(reqKey);

        // Just get a rough estimate of what the size of this upload will be 
        if (s3Rec == null)
        {
            ++reqFilesToUpload;
            reqSizeToUpload += fsRec.getSize();
        }
    }

    long uploadTimeGuessMs = (long)((double)reqSizeToUpload/estUploadRateBPS*1000.0);

    printAndLog("Estimated upload: " + natFmt.format(reqFilesToUpload) + " files, " + Utils.readableFileSize(reqSizeToUpload) + 
            ", Estimated time " + Utils.readableElapsedTime(uploadTimeGuessMs));

    globalTimer.start();
    rptTimer.start();
    for (FileSystemRecord fsRec : fileSystemState.toList())
    {
        String reqKey = PathConverter.pathToKey(PathConverter.makeRelativePath(fileSystemState.getRootPath(), fsRec.getFullpath()));

        if (PathConverter.validate(reqKey))
        {
            LocalS3MetadataRecord s3Rec = s3Metadata.getRecord(reqKey);

            //TODO compare and deal with size mismatches.  Maybe go and look at last-mod dates.
            if (s3Rec == null)
            {
                indvTimer.start();
                uploadFileToBucket(s3, syncParms.getS3Bucket(), fsRec.getFullpath(), reqKey);
                indvTimer.stop();

                ++totFilesUploaded;
                totSizeUploaded += fsRec.getSize();

                logOnly("Uploaded: Size=" + fsRec.getSize() + ", " + indvTimer.stopDeltaMs() + " ms, File=" + fsRec.getFullpath() + ", toKey=" + reqKey);

                if (totSizeUploaded > rptLastSize + rptSizeInterval)
                {
                    long invSizeUploaded = totSizeUploaded - rptLastSize;

                    long nowMs = rptTimer.intervalMs();
                    long invElapMs = nowMs - rptLastMs;
                    long remSize = reqSizeToUpload - totSizeUploaded;
                    double progessPct = (double)totSizeUploaded/reqSizeToUpload*100.0;
                    double mbps = (invElapMs > 0) ? invSizeUploaded/1e6/(invElapMs/1000.0) : 0.0;
                    long remMs = (long)((double)remSize/((double)invSizeUploaded/invElapMs));

                    printOnly("Progress: " + d2Fmt.format(progessPct) + "%, " + Utils.readableFileSize(totSizeUploaded) + " of " + 
                            Utils.readableFileSize(reqSizeToUpload) + ", Rate " + d3Fmt.format(mbps) + " MB/s, " + 
                            "Time rem " + Utils.readableElapsedTime(remMs));

                    rptLastMs = nowMs;
                    rptLastFilesUploaded = totFilesUploaded;
                    rptLastSize = totSizeUploaded;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ++totFilesSkipped;
            totSizeSkipped += fsRec.getSize();

            logOnly("Skipped (Invalid chars): Size=" + fsRec.getSize() + ", " + fsRec.getFullpath() + ", toKey=" + reqKey);

        }

    }

    globalTimer.stop();

    double mbps = 0.0;

    if (globalTimer.stopDeltaMs() > 0)
        mbps = totSizeUploaded/1e6/(globalTimer.stopDeltaMs()/1000.0);

    printAndLog("Actual upload: " + natFmt.format(totFilesUploaded) + " files, " + Utils.readableFileSize(totSizeUploaded) + 
            ", Time " + Utils.readableElapsedTime(globalTimer.stopDeltaMs()) + ", Rate " + d3Fmt.format(mbps) + " MB/s");

    if (totFilesSkipped > 0)
        printAndLog("Skipped Files: " + natFmt.format(totFilesSkipped) + " files, " + Utils.readableFileSize(totSizeSkipped)); 
}

private void uploadFileToBucket(AmazonS3 amazonS3, String bucketName, String filePath, String fileKey)
{    
    File inFile = new File(filePath);

    ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
    objectMetadata.addUserMetadata(Const.LAST_MOD_KEY, Long.toString(inFile.lastModified()));
    objectMetadata.setLastModified(new Date(inFile.lastModified()));

    PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileKey, inFile).withMetadata(objectMetadata);

    // Amazon S3 never stores partial objects; if during this call an exception wasn't thrown, the entire object was stored.  
    amazonS3.putObject(por);  
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "gather its results"? What does the dispatcher need to do that can't be done within the worker thread?

Comment: @shmosel Aggregate the progress across all threads and intelligently dispatch new work which may include reducing or increasing the number of worker threads.

Comment: Doesn't that imply waiting for all threads to finish?

Comment: @shmosel No. Eventually all threads will finish but this job could run for weeks.  So each individual thread would only be aware of its small piece of the bigger workload.  During that time the number of executing threads may need to be adjusted to take advantage of or be throttled due to  available network bandwidth.  Plus, overall workload management including restarting failed threads can only be done by the dispatcher.  So more has to be done that just wait for the threads to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are at right package. you should use ExecutorService API.
This removes burden of waiting and watching for thread's notification.
Example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;


public class ExecutorEx{
    static class ThreadA implements Runnable{
        int id;
        public ThreadA(int id){
            this.id = id;
        }
        public void run(){
            //To simulate some work
            try{Thread.sleep(Math.round(Math.random()*100));}catch(Exception e){}
            // to show message
            System.out.println(this.id + "--Test Message" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        int poolSize = 10;
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
        int i=0;
        while(i<100){
            pool.submit(new ThreadA(i));
            i++;
        }
        pool.shutdown();
        while(!pool.isTerminated()){
            pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    }
}
```

And if you want to return something from your thread will need to implement Callable instead of Runnable(call() instead of run()) and collect returned values in Future object array, that you can iterate over later.

Comment: On what basis you want to submit threads? Is next submit dependent on the previous (This sounds single threaded approach)? It will help us to understand if you can share a sample code of dispatcher at least.

Comment: I am breaking up a serial process into multiple threads to significantly reduce time.  This is a job that could run for days or weeks so I need to be able to track and report progress and increase or decrease the number of active threads depending on throughput rate.  So getting the results from each thread's completion would allow the calculation of overall progress and transfer rate.

Comment: Just an idea: how about passing all future objects to another watcher thread instance which can alter dispatcher (number of thread, etc) accordingly, same time watcher thread can also put failed objects back into input queue.